# ServiceProvider register a services with construct params in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm use laravel 5.1 and I have this issues.

in my AppServiceProvider.php register method

```
$this->app->singleton('PingppServices', function ($app, $params) {
    return new \App\Services\PingppServices($params['sid']);
});
```

in PingppServices.php

```
private $sid;

public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->sid = $params['sid'];
}

public function foo()
{
    echo $this->sid;
}
```

in controller I use this to call it

```
$pingppServices = app('PingppServices', ['sid' => 1]);
$pingppServices->foo();
```

So my question is, in laravel 5.0, I can do like this `app('PingppServices', 1);`, in 5.1 the second argument must be an array. I see the app() method has no change, so what change?

And is this right way to resolve a services with construct params ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It it hard to say, without having the insight of the purpose of the class and an overview over the whole code.

In general I would things you pass to the constructor of a class are mostly dependencies and configuration variables. Anything relate to runtime data should have it's separate setter or should be passed as argument to the method where is is required.

Like I sad it is really hard to say, without having more insight.

Example:

```
class Foobar {
   private $pingppService;
   public function __construct(PingppServices $pingppService) {
      $this->pingppService = $pingppService; 
   }

   public function wtf() {
      $this->pingppService->setParams(Request::all());
      $this->pingppService->foo();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like you said, in Laravel 5.1, app() method is

```
/**
 * Get the available container instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $make
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
{
    if (is_null($make)) {
        return Container::getInstance();
    }

    return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);
}
```

And at last, it will call function `build($concrete, array $parameters = [])`.

So, the second argument must be an array.